# What is Nuget UNC path and how can I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, nuget

When compiling my UWP project I have the following output before my build starts:

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share.
```

I believe this is causing my UWP packages to have errors because I am missing the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform reference.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somehow I had some bad package sources. I'm not sure how this happened, but I found them by going to

**Tools** -> **Nuget Package Manager** -> **Package Manager Settings**, **Package Sources** category.

In there I found two strange entries:

- \\MyShare
- http://MyServer

I unchecked these two values and clicked **OK**:

[image]

That seemed to fix it for me - after making that change my project compiled.